# How to safely unmount a component in React?

Tags: reactjs

By clicking on the button in one component, I delete the component in the parent with such code:

```
// componentA.jsx
class ComponentA extends React.PureComponent {
  removeB() {
    this.setState({ mounted: false })
  }

  renderB() {
    if (!this.state.mounted) {
      return null
    }
    return <ComponentB />
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.renderB()}
      <ComponentC onClick={this.removeB} />
    </div>
  }
}

// componentB.jsx
class ComponentB extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return ...
  }
}

// componentC.jsx
class ComponentC extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.props.onClick} />
  }
}
```

I get the error:

> Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because the `this` variable inside function `removeB` refers to the wrong scope (in your example the scope of `ComponentC`, it should refer to the correct scope, which is `ComponentA`).

You should correctly bind the event handler to the scope of `ComponentA` before passing it.

You can do it in couple of ways:

```
class ComponentA extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
     this.removeB = this.removeB.bind(this);  // Bind event handlers in constructor
  }

  removeB() {
    this.setState({ mounted: false })
  }

  ....

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.renderB()}
      <ComponentC onClick={this.removeB} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Or:

```
class ComponentA extends React.PureComponent {
  removeB = () => {
    this.setState({ mounted: false })
  } // Using arrow function to bind function to the current lexical scoping

  ....

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.renderB()}
      <ComponentC onClick={this.removeB} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

You can read more about JS lexical scoping here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Also, React document mentioned about binding event handlers to the correct scope here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html